# Переключение между версиями python в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

У меня в Ubuntu 16.04 стоит 2 версии python: python2(при использовании 
`python -V` 2.7.12) и python3 (при использовании 
`python3 -V` 3.5.2).
Я решил установить свежую версию (3.6.5.). Скачав архив и выполнив следующие действия:

- переходим в папку с архивом выполнив `$ tar xvf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz`
- переходим в разархивированную папку с питоном `cd Python-3.6.5/`
- `$ ./configure`
- `$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
- `$ sudo make altinstall`

Но при вводе `python3 -V` выводит 3.5.2 а не то что я установил (3.6.5).

При попытке создать виртуальное окружение `$ python3 -m venv <myenvname>` папка создается а вот команда `$ virtualenv <myenvname>` выдает следующее

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /media/disciple/Локальный диск/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog/flask_blog/bin/python2
Not overwriting existing python script /media/disciple/Локальный диск/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog/flask_blog/bin/python (you must use /media/disciple/Локальный диск/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog/flask_blog/bin/python2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable /media/disciple/Локальный диск/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog/flask_blog/bin/python2 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/media/disciple/\u041b\u043e\u043a\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0441\u043a/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog' (should be u'/media/disciple/\u041b\u043e\u043a\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0441\u043a/python_win/work/blogs/flask_microblog/flask_blog')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

1) Как мне выбрать версию python 3 которая будет использоваться по умолчанию (глобально на всей машине) ?. Например в системе стоит 3.5.2 по умолчанию а я хочу 3.6.5 по умолчанию. Не сломает ли это работу терминила, gnome, саму систему ? 
2) Как переключаться между версиями python для каждого проекта (папки) ?
3) Устанавливая различные дополнительные пакеты через pip их нужно устанавливать через команду `pip3` для python 3 и просто `pip` для python 2 ?

Comment: Вам стоит разбить вопрос на несколько, подробнее описав ваш случай (в зависимости от конкретной задачи, *противоположные*  (противоречащие друг другу) рекомендации применимы -- зачем вам несколько Питонов, что вы запускать хотите их используя, какое назначение у машины, итд). И уж точно про конкретную ошибку с virtualenv следует отдельный вопрос задать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Как мне выбрать версию python 3 которая будет использоваться по умолчанию (глобально на всей машине) ?

Версия python3 задаётся симлинком, у меня это выглядит так:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 29 10:42 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
```

но менять таки не рекомендую, есть завязки на конкретную версию, в первую очередь в том, что именно для неё стягиваются пакеты по зависимостям.

> 2) Как переключаться между версиями python для каждого проекта (папки) ?

virtualenv создаёт переходник для запуска конкретной версии Python по пути `$ENV/bin/python`, где `$ENV` это каталог созданного virtualenv. Для его использования есть несколько вариантов, но самый прямой - включить `$ENV/bin/activate` (командой `.`, она же `source`, в sh или bash), она добавляет этот bin в начало `$PATH` и ставит ещё несколько переменных окружения по обстановке. Далее за счёт `$PATH` этот `python` будет подключаться вперёд системных.

> 3) Устанавливая различные дополнительные пакеты через pip их нужно устанавливать через команду pip3 для python 3 и просто pip для python 2 ?

В созданном через `virtualenv` окружении надо использовать просто `pip`. Вне их, в основной системе - `pip2` или `pip3` (для Ubuntu именно так). То, что `pip` сейчас является алиасом для `pip2`, может поменяться в следующих версиях.

Что у вас сломано в создании по virtualenv, я не могу понять по этому описанию. Попробуйте просто переустановить пакеты, относящиеся к питону.

UPDATE: про virtualenv. Вот пример. Создаю первое окружение с python2:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 /var/tmp/p2.1
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /var/tmp/p2.1/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /var/tmp/p2.1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

Второе точно так же:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 /var/tmp/p2.2/
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /var/tmp/p2.2/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /var/tmp/p2.2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

Ставим numpy в первое:

```
$ ( . /var/tmp/p2.1/bin/activate; pip install numpy )
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/4d/418dda252cf92bad00ab82d6b2a856e7843b47a5c2f084aed34b14b67d64/numpy-1.14.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.1MB 458kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.2
```

Во второе не ставим. Проверяем что получилось - на bash чистом от настроек (я запускал новый терминал в screen, можно запустить иксовый terminal, konsole или что угодно взамен). Обратите внимание, после activate я для запуска питона говорю просто "python", без указания версии или самого окружения (оно всё уже установлено):

```
$ . /var/tmp/p2.1/bin/activate
(p2.1) $ echo $PATH
/var/tmp/p2.1/bin:/home/netch/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
(p2.1) $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.zeros(4)
array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

В соседнем терминале запускаем второе окружение:

```
$ . /var/tmp/p2.2/bin/activate
(p2.2) $ echo $PATH
/var/tmp/p2.2/bin:/home/netch/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
(p2.2) $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

как видим, во втором окружении numpy нет: мы его туда не ставили. Окружения разные с разными свойствами. А первый элемент в $PATH (вывод команды `echo $PATH`) показывает каталог, который был добавлен activate из virtualenv.

И ещё для убедительности рассказа можно показать, что файлы numpy в результате запуска `pip install numpy` появились в p2.1, но не в p2.2:

```
(p2.2) $ find /var/tmp/p2.1/ | grep numpy | head -2
/var/tmp/p2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
/var/tmp/p2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py
(p2.2) $ find /var/tmp/p2.2/ | grep numpy | head -2
(p2.2) $
```

что не ставили - того нет и не подключается, если разные версии установлены в разные окружения - будут разные версии. Причём: если в дефолтном питоне установлен пакет (numpy в моём примере) - из окружения он не видится (по крайней мере в тех версиях, что я проверял).

Comment: Подробнее с ответом на вопрос 2) : как с помощью virtualenv  активировать/установить дефолтный питон например 3.6.5 ?

Comment: @discipleartem Никак, Вы криво прочли. virtualenv не меняет _дефолтный_ питон системы, он устанавливает конкретный заданный для конкретного сгенерированного окружения. Если же хотите переключать для проекта эту версию на ходу, надо регенерировать окружение или переключаться на другое, например, сменой $PATH.

Comment: Думаю, вам вначале надо понять принцип работы поиска исполняемого файла по значению $PATH и посмотреть на образцы такого поиска в случае вне virtualenv-окружения и в нём. После этого вопросов будет в разы меньше.

Comment: подскажите хотя бы правильный поисковой запрос, потому что в гайдах об этом не упоминают, а пишут что нужно выполнить такую команду и все

Comment: @discipleartem я расширил ответ, смотрите. Ещё более подробно это, извините, самые основы работы в unix шелле (переменные окружения, роль $PATH и т.п.), я уже тут расписывать не буду, это просто читать книги типа "Linux для пользователя", "Секреты Unix" и т.д.